# Leaflet on mouseout event not firing when changing iconUrl

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mouseout

I am experiencing an issue with leaflet and it's `mouseout` event.

In the code below, sometimes (particulary if you move the mouse fast), the mouseout event is not triggered. The `Mouse out !` doesn't appear in the console.

I found out that this behaviour is related to the icon replacement. A simple `layer.setStyle` works every time. (Here I use the [leaflet-gpx](https://github.com/mpetazzoni/leaflet-gpx) plugin but it works the same way as [leaflet's IconUrl or shadowUrl](https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/))

```
// This works every time
gpxPath.on('mouseover', function (e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    layer.options.marker_options.startIconUrl = 'myHoverIconStartUrl';
    layer.options.marker_options.endIconUrl = 'myHoverIconEndUrl';
    layer.reload();
});

gpxPath.on('mouseout', function (e) {
    console.log('Mouse out !')
    var layer = e.target;
    /* those two lines below cause the issue */
    layer.options.marker_options.startIconUrl = '';
    layer.options.marker_options.endIconUrl = '';
    layer.reload();
});
```

I know that the mouseout event sometimes causes issues like this one, but in this particular case I am forced to use the leaflet events and I am a little bit out of ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you trying to make markers display a different icon on hover?

It's hard to tell without an example, but what I think is happening is:

Your `mouseout`event isn't getting triggered reliably because the `mouseover` event is ran continuously, as long as your mouse is positioned on it, every time the icons rebuild.

You may notice this if you add a `console.log` in that function as well. You can happen to move off while it is rebuilding, so you don't trigger the `mouseout` event reliably.

If so, try something like:

```
line.once('mouseover', function () {
    //switch to icons

});

line.on('mouseout', function () {
    //clear icons
    
    //Prevent mouseover event from firing continuously if/when the icon changes
    line.once('mouseover', function () {
        //switch to icons
    });
});
```

Comment: Works for my icon switching! Very clean, thanks.